# Android collapse an element?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to "collapse" (in my case, width=0, and the element to the left of it will expand and take its place) an element (in my case an ImageView) in Android ui when it's been set to invisible?

Comment: maybe element.setlayoutparams() could help

Comment: I'm under a relative layout though? I thought that's only doable using a linear layout?

Comment: what if you just inflate the old view with the new one?

Comment: do you have your layout for every element specified in xml or programmatically?

Comment: xml, but i'm adjusting this one programmically

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the right layout, you can apply a positive `weight` to both elements with `layout_width=match_parent`. Fiddle with the weights until they look right.

When you want one to disappear just call `.setVisibility(View.VISIBILITY_GONE)`. The element will vanish and the other one will fill the missing space.

Comment: If you are not using a good layout for this, consider wrapping a LinearLayout around both elements - you can nest layouts.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason even when I call setVisibility(View.VISIBILITY_GONE), the other ones are not filling it's space.

Comment: All the elements that you want to fill the space MUST have a weight>0. I have only done this with LinearLayout - I'm not sure it will work for RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `setVisibility(View.GONE)`? That will make the view take up no space and other views will take up the space it occupied.

Comment: No, it still takes space. And the other views are not expanded

Comment: Post your XML layout. Since you are using `RelativeLayout` you will probably have to move the other views manually as well

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the old version of view and instead of that one add a new one

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
item.addView(child);
```